Make a common dynamic converter extension in C#
I have a new project where I am adding some important string manupulation extensions.
I am trying to add a dynamic conversion extension as well.
As of now, I have done this
public static T To<T>(dynamic value) =>
       value.Equals(DBNull.Value) 
           ? default(T) 
           : Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));

But still while converting int, if we pass null value, error is occured.
How can I handle the error here?

Try value is null ? default(T) : ...

FYI Null != DbNull

Or value is T t

Having a method like this seems like a terrible idea right from the start. Also, every time you use dynamic, a kitten dies.

DbNull.Value represents an instance of the DbNull class, which is an object that is analogous to a null in DB. null is a keyword that represents a non-object. The two are not the same and your error is that you confounded the two. You probably wanted to check for both:
((value == null) || value.Equals(DBNull.Value)) ? default(T) : Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T))

